# How can i find name of a zip file and extract The contents to a particular folder using Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am building a docker images .For my image i need to extract a zip file under test_folder.
Name of this zip file keep changes . So i cant hardcode the name of zip file in my dockerfile
How can i write a Docker file for finding this zip file under test_folder and extract the contents of this file to particular folder for eg:/tmp inside the docker container

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is using wildcards:

```
COPY test_folder/*.zip /tmp/
```

You can of course narrow the matching by using a more specific wildcard, but that depends on the structure of your file's name.

Comment: Sorry i cant use wildcards for my copy . That's the issue here .I need to find name of zip file and then copy it